Is the time complexity of this method constant?
I've been tasked to find the time complexity of this method, but I am not sure why it's constant.
What I had thought was that the overall time complexity was n2^n because the outer loop runs n times and inner loop runs 2^k times because k is being multiplied by a factor of two for each time the outer loop runs. However, when I tested the method out using System.nanoTime(), the time seem to stay constant for increasing sizes of the data. I'm not sure if I'm correct or wrong, but if I'm wrong, and the method has a constant time complexity, can you please explain why? Thank you!
public static void f6(int n) {
    int k = 1, a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= k * 2; j += 1) {
            a = i + j;
        }
        k = k * 2;
    }
}

Test-left column:function name; middle column:number of items; right column: time taken:


Of course its not constant. The problem is, measuring the time some code takes is vastly more complex than simply using nanoTime. use JMH, and ensure the test times are long enough.

It might be worth looking to see what the optimiser has done to this code. Since there is no return value the entire thing may have been replaced with a return. Make it int f6(int n) and change the inner loop to a += i+j. Otherwise there are compilers about that will spot that a = i + 2^i on exiting the inner loop and that last time through the loop i=n-1.  IOW they will deduce that returning n-1+k^(n-1) can be computed in constant time and an external user will never know the difference. Try timing it in debug mode when it executes code verbatim and you might get more meaningful answers.

You might be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

@MartinBrown Optimizers can also probably figure out that a is only ever written, not read, meaning that it can be removed; which leaves the inner loop empty, so it can be removed.

If not the compiler, the runtime also does optimisation if you're running this repeatedly and it notices.

@yshavit on the most aggressive top flight optimising compilers today you have to at least appear to print out the return result of the function being benchmarked or do something else with it that has side effects to be certain that it gets executed under full global optimisation. I tend to use if (result ==42) printf("Surprise\n"); for this purpose. So far no optimiser has seen through this deception.

@MartinBrown Sure, but the inner loop isn't printing anything, nor does it have any other apparent side effects. And I'd guess the optimizer can figure that out.

Oh actually, sorry — were you just suggesting a workaround for what I was saying?


What I had thought was that the overall time complexity was n2^n because the outer loop runs n times and inner loop runs 2^k times because k is being multiplied by a factor of two for each time the outer loop runs.

Well, O(n2n) is certainly an upper bound on the method's asymptotic complexity.  Your analysis is correct as far as it goes.  But if you look just a little deeper, you can get a tighter one that still has simple form.
Write out some of the inner-loop iteration counts:
1  2  4  8 ...

all the way up to 2n-1.  The sum of all of those can be expressed as Σi = 1…n 2i-1.  If you don't already know the result of that sum off the top of your head then it's one you should learn. And I'll let you do that.

However, when I tested the method out using System.nanoTime(), the time seem to stay constant for increasing sizes of the data.

Benchmarking is a lot more difficult than it may seem.  There are multiple reasons for a naive benchmark such as you describe to be inaccurate.  Compiler optimizations, JIT behavior, machine load, and even some degree of random fluctuation can all conspire against you, at least with respect to estimating asymptotic complexity via running time.
Consider, for example, that a sufficiently clever compiler might recognize that the whole method can be reduced to just a handful of operations -- constant indeed -- and emit code that just does that instead of actually running the loops.  I don't think your compiler is smart enough for that, but in theory, one could be.

Would the sum be 2^n-1? In that case, why would this be a tighter bound if it can be simplified to 2^n?

@WoojinRho, 1 * (2^n) - 1 is a tighter bound than your n * (2^n) because the factor of 1 in the former is asymptotically smaller than the corresponding factor of n in the latter.  It would be conventional, however, to ignore the - 1 and just write it as O(2^n) (not your proposed O(n2^n)).  Perhaps you're not appreciating that that covers all the operations in the whole loop nest, not just the inner loop.

You defined a and k variables as integers and (at least the k variable) can't be increased to ^2 more than 32 times. So the JVM "knows" that the equation of the k = k^2 has sense only the first 31 times and will not do excessive iterations.
More of that, if you don't use the result after calculation the JVM also can decide not to execute the calculation.
So, solution:

change int a,k to the long a,k (consider that now function has sencse only with n <= 64).
Use result (sysout will be enough)


If you look at the values for k (which defines how often the inner loop runs) you will find these values:
1  2  4  8 ... 536870912  1073741824  -2147483648  0  0  0

The number of times the inner loop runs is limited and for sufficient large values of n (at n = 31). After that the run time of this method only increases linearly with the value of n (since the outer loop still runs from 32 to n).
So for values of n from 1 to 31 it runs in O(2^n), for larger values it runs in O(n).
